# Assigning rows in a tensor throws "None values not supported"

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, matrix

I have written a program to update rows from one tensor to another tensor. Below is a very basic idea of what I want to achieve

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    A = tf.Variable(
        [[[0.2, 0.8, 0.1], [0.0, 1.0, 3.0], [0.0, 1.0, 3.0]], [[0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.5], [0.0, 1.0, 3.0]],
         [[0.0, 1.0, 0.6], [0.0, 1.0, 0.4], [0.0, 1.0, 3.0]]])
    B = tf.Variable(
        [[[1.2, 1.8, 1.1], [1.1, 1.1, 3.1], [1.1, 1.1, 3.1]], [[1.1, 1.1, 1.1], [1.1 ,1.1, 1.5], [1.1, 1.1, 3.1]],
         [[1.0, 1.0, 1.6], [1.1, 1.1, 1.4], [1.1, 1.1, 3.1]]])

    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    parent1 = 0
    parent2 = 1

    print("\n A")
    print(sess.run(A[parent2][0]))
    # A=[0. 1. 1.]
    print("\n B")
    print(sess.run(B[parent1][0]))
    # B=[0.2 0.8 0.1]
    print("\n Result")
    B = B[0,0].assign(A[1,0])
    print(sess.run(B[0]))
    #  Result
    # [[0.  1.  1. ]
    #  [1.1 1.1 3.1]
    #  [1.1 1.1 3.1]]
```

This works. My problem comes in when I add a second operator:

```
print("\n Result")
B = B[0,0].assign(A[1,0])
B = B[1,0].assign(A[0,0])
```

Then I get hit with (full stack trace at the bottom):

```
ValueError: None values not supported.
```

It seems for some reason it tries to do an internal convertion to a tensor and for some reason, a None type gets passed. I tried evaluating the variable before trying to continue that also does not work The idea is to get to a point where I can make use of a loop like so:

```
for i in indexes:
    B = B[parent1][i].assign(A[parent2][i])
    B = B[parent2][i].assign(A[parent1][i])
```

Full stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 527, in _apply_op_helper
    preferred_dtype=default_dtype)
  File "tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1224, in internal_convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 305, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
    return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
  File "tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 246, in constant
    allow_broadcast=True)
  File "tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 284, in _constant_impl
    allow_broadcast=allow_broadcast))
  File "tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_util.py", line 454, in make_tensor_proto
    raise ValueError("None values not supported.")
ValueError: None values not supported.
```

Comment: this looks like a glitch, try raising an issue with tf github

Answer (score 0):

Even though I haven't figured out this bug, one current walk around to this problem is using `tf.assign`.

```py
op1 = tf.assign(B[0,0], A[1,0])
op2 = tf.assign(B[1,0], A[0,0])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    sess.run([op1, op2])
    print(B.eval())
#[[[0.  1.  1. ]
#   [1.1 1.1 3.1]
#   [1.1 1.1 3.1]]

#  [[0.2 0.8 0.1]
#   [1.1 1.1 1.5]
#   [1.1 1.1 3.1]]

#  [[1.  1.  1.6]
#   [1.1 1.1 1.4]
#   [1.1 1.1 3.1]]]
```

Comment: Thank you but I ended up creating a tensor of 1s and 0s, created an inverse matrix of it and multiplying my tensors with it to get my result. Also removed the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

B = B[0,0].assign(A[1,0])
B = B[1,0].assign(A[0,0])

I tried replicating your code and I didn't get the same error but instead get "Sliced assignment is only supported for variables". Which is true as well since once B is sliced it is no longer a variable but becomes a tensor.

The numpy style slicing notation (tensor[a:b]) is just shorthand for the longer tensorflow notation tf.slice(tensor, a, a+b) which outputs a new tensor operation on the graph (see https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/slice).

Hope this helps in understanding the issue.